# How are classes managed in C++ memory management - study

Tags: c++, class

I am studying at a nightschool for basic C++ programming, and I have some questions to revise that make not much sense to me, I mean I think I know the answers but I would like to run by people here and experts to get a good understanding, I've tried looking for specific answers online through google but its hard to find.

in the following code how will the different variables (*mystring, msize, x, y,
*px, new int) be managed in C++ memory management?

```
class myclass
{
public:
char *mystring = “thestring”;
int msize = 200;
int myfunc(int x)
{
int y = 20;
x = x + y;
return x * y;
}
int main(void)
{
int *px = new int;
cin >> x;
cout << myfunc(x);
delete px;
}
}
```

Now I assume, that when a class is instantiated in memory, given a memory location beginning and end, it creates a copy of the values in order of declaration in code, so I'm guessing the char* gets a pointer of some sort.

int msize will be after and will be an 8bit value with address after.

but I assume functions are called in class ?

Comment: I can't really figure out exactly what you're asking, but if you're asking how all of your variables get laid out in memory, the answer is that the C++ standard doesn't mandate any particular layout. It's entirely up to the compiler, and different conforming C++ compilers might lay things out totally differently in memory. In fact, the same compiler might lay things out differently depending on many factors (optimizations, target architecture, etc...) so without a reference to a particular compiler and command line options, the best answer you can hope to get is "it depends."

Comment: You have free functions, why would they be called in any class? (Also there isn't a single class in this code)

Comment: @cdhowie you see i thought the question was vague itself, I'm not quite sure what I't means by how it is managed in memory management.

Comment: That code does not compile.

Comment: @RobertRichborough If you don't know what your own question means than how are we supposed to?

Comment: @cdhowie I was hoping someone would know because its a question I have been given to revise, I apologize.

Comment: @RobertRichborough Is the source code in your question copied directly from the question you are trying to revise, or is it something you wrote?

Comment: @cdhowie directly copied.

Comment: In that case you should find a better book/course. This code is *absolutely* wrong and won't compile

Comment: The way your code is written, you could say that nothing is allocated, your code does not compile

Comment: The code made much more sense before you wrapped it all into a class.  Pointing a char* at a string literal is dangerous.

Comment: @RobertRichborough As others have said, [the code isn't even valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfcabfbcae50b6b3). It's rather useless to try to reason about the memory allocation properties of code that is ill-formed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's my best guess at the code you meant:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

char *mystring = "thestring";  // extremely dangerous type mismatch, don't do this
int msize = 200;

int myfunc(int x)
{
  int y = 20;

  x = x + y;

  return x * y;
}

int main(void)
{
  int *px = new int;

  cin >> *px;
  cout << myfunc(*px);
  delete px;

  return 0;
}
```

The variables 'mystring' and 'msize' are global variables whose memory is statically allocated by the compiler.  These variables exist for the entire duration of any run of the program and, typically, can be accessed by name by any part of your program.

'x' and 'y' are local variables to the function 'myfunc.'  They exist and are accessible by name only within each call to that function.

'px' is a local variable to the function 'main.'  'main' is somewhat special in that, typically, it is the entry point for your program and when it returns the program exits.  So, 'px's lifetime is essentially for the duration of the program although it can only be accessed by that name within the 'main' function.

'new int' explicitly dynamically allocates memory for an int that is then available until it is deallocated by a matching, explicit call to delete.

Typically, memory for a local variable is pushed onto (and popped off of) a running thread's stack as the thread enters and exits from the variable's scope (with constructors and destructors being called as appropriate too).  Dynamically allocated memory is ultimately, explicitly managed per variable through calls to new and delete in C++ (or malloc and free in C).